# How to convert the Java api KStream to Scala api KStream?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Our library has dataprocessors (Scala code) that uses the typical kafka-stream:

```scala
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream
```

The reason for moving to `kafka-stream-scala` is the weird return types whenever I use functions like groupBy, selectByKey, etc.

```scala
(builder: StreamsBuilder, stream: KStream[String, Event]) =>
 val wgCreatedStream = stream.groupBy((_,v) => 
  v.payload match {
   case x:WorkgroupCreated => x.id //this is a String
  })
```

Take this code for example. `StreamsBuilder` results to `KGroupedStream[Nothing,Event]`

When I used these imports:

```scala
import org.apache.kafka.streams.scala.{ByteArrayWindowStore, StreamsBuilder}
import org.apache.kafka.streams.scala.kstream.{Grouped, KStream, Materialized}
import org.apache.kafka.streams.scala.Serdes.{String,Long}
```

return type finally changed to `KGroupedStream[String,Event]`

**What I'm really hoping for:**
*To use `kafka-stream-scala` without refactoring our dataprocessor*

If YES, that's fantastic, esp. if there's examples!
If NO... it'll be a painful journey. :( (but thanks anyway)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, after a chat with my workmate, I immediately found an answer. -___-

from `org.apache.kafka.streams.scala.ImplicitConversions`,
 
there's a `wrapKStream()` that converts 
 `streams.kstream.KStream` to `streams.scala.kstream.KStream`

As for the other way around, just call the `inner` method directly. Same goes for KTable.